# $\mathbb{R}$ as a family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $\epsilon > 0 $ and let $A_q$ be an indexed family of sets where $A_q = (q-\epsilon, q+\epsilon)$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Now we would like to prove that $\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} A_q = \mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively, I feel why it is so, however, I don't know how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Remember that $(\mathbb Q; \le)$ is a dense suborder of  $(\mathbb R; \le)$. Recall what *dense* means in this context. This will immediately imply that
$$
\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb Q} (q- \epsilon, q + \epsilon) = \mathbb R
$$
for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: This is an exercise to make sure you understood all definitions involved in it - there really isn't anything more than that to it.

Comment: I would be careful assuming that this is about orderings, and not topologies or metrics. Still, the concept of "dense" is transferrable between the different fields.